# What wrong in this java inheritance code?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, default-constructor

```
class Bird{
    public Bird(){
    }

}

class Falcon extends Bird{
    public Falcon(){
    }

    public void fly(){
    System.out.println("Fly method in falcon");}
}

public class Test{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Bird b=new Falcon();
        b.fly();    // error on this line
    }
}
```

The above code gives me a compile time error. Can anyone tell me why? I am using JDK 1.8

Comment: `Bird` Doesn't have a `fly` method specified in its' *public **interface***.

Comment: *"gives me a compile time error"* is an incomplete description of your problem. What error?

Comment: To elaborate a bit on Elliott's comment: When the type has a static type of `Bird`, Java will only let you invoke methods on it that it knows all Birds have. You didn't declare a method `fly()` on Bird, so as far as Java knows, this Bird could be one that doesn't have that method -- and thus, it won't let you invoke it. Java doesn't know at compile time that `b` is specifically a Falcon, because you explicitly told it that it's just some kind of Bird.

Comment: I get error *"The method fly() is undefined for the type Bird"*. Which part of this error message do you not understand?

Comment: @yshavit: thanks now I get it.

Comment: @Andreas I was just confused with why I am not able to use Falcon method. Now, I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas I don't think this is a concept that's always obvious to beginners.  So it makes perfect sense to me that even with the error message, the reason could be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, if you declare something as a `Bird`, the only things the compiler is "allowed" to know is that it has the methods defined for `Bird`.  It's not allowed to know about any methods declared for any subclasses of `Bird` (unless you use a cast).

Suppose you were to say

```
Bird b = new Falcon();
someMethod(b);
```

and then, in `someMethod`:

```
public void someMethod(Bird b) {
    b.fly();
}
```

This is essentially the same thing you're doing.  But the only thing `someMethod` knows about `b` is that it's some kind of `Bird`.  It can't tell, at that point, whether it's a `Falcon`, or something like an `Emu` or `Kiwi` that doesn't have a flight method (since `someMethod` could be called from some other place in the program).

Sure, it might be possible for the program, when it sees `b.fly()`, to check *at run time* whether this kind of bird has a `fly` method, and throw an exception if it doesn't.  Some languages do that.  Java doesn't.

Also, if you're thinking that the compiler should know in this case:

```
Bird b = new Falcon();
b.fly();
```

that `b` is a `Falcon`, because it just created it as a `Falcon`: that doesn't work, because it would require overly complicated language rules to allow a compiler to see that `b.fly()` will always work in this case, but won't always work in other cases.  Language rules need to be kept fairly simple and consistent, to ensure that programs will work on any compiler that meets the standard.

However, if you use a cast, you *can* get at methods of the subclasses:

```
Bird b = new Falcon();
((Falcon)b).fly();
```

This says to check (at run time) whether `b` is a `Falcon`.  If it is, you can now use the methods defined for `Falcon`.  If it isn't, you'll get an exception.

Comment: Great explanation! As additional commentary for "some languages do that. Java doesn't" -- this is, broadly speaking (and glossing over some subtleties), the difference between a "statically typed" language like Java, and a "dynamically typed" language (like Python, JavaScript and others).